# ChoiceField, доступ к видимому значению

Tags: python, django

с помощью django.forms делаю dropdown меню, как поле ChoiceField. Варианты задаю как кортеж:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):

CHOICES = (
    ('CH1', 'Choice 1'),
    ('CH2', 'Choice 2'),
)

menu = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CHOICES)
```

на основе выбора пользователя, создаётся документ/шаблон в который передаётся значение, выбранное пользователем. если передать в шаблон переменную "menu", то на месте шаблонного тега переменной - появится CH1 или CH2, а мне нужно чтобы передалось именно, то что видит пользователь - Choice 1 или Choice 2. Как это осуществить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data = request.POST
menu = dict(MyForm.CHOICES).get(data['menu'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Изменено:

Возможно Вы не так его истолковали. Приведу боевой код.

У меня есть модель с таким полем:

```
class Ticket(models.Model):
    """
    Класс объявления.
    """

    type = models.CharField(
        max_length = 7,
        choices = (
            ('sell', _l(u'Продажа')),
            ('buy', _l(u'Покупка')),
            ('ex', _l(u'Обмен')),
            ('rent', _l(u'Аренда')),
        ),
        default = 'sell',
        help_text = _l(u'Тип объявления.'),
        verbose_name = _l(u'Тип')
    )
```

Под эту модель существует форма:

```
class TicketForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """
    Форма Подачи/редактирования объявления.
    """
    class Meta:
        model = Ticket
```

В виде я её создаю и передаю в шаблон:

```
add_form = TicketForm()
return render_to_response('ticket_add.html', RequestContext(request,
        {
            'add_form': add_form,
        }))
```

В шаблоне я могу доступиться к метке выбора через такую комбинацию:

```
{{ add_form.type.field.choices.1.1 }}
```

Что выведет в шаблоне слово "Покупка", которое является меткой второго выбора. Т.е. в обычном коде доступиться к этому значению можно так:

```
add_form['type']field.choices[1][1]
```

Оба варианта только что проверил - всё работает.

Comment: Первый элемент кортежа будет также <option value> в HTML форме, а вдруг в меню будут русские/спец символы и т.п.

Comment: Плохо понимаю что нужно. Нужно показать текст соответственно выбранному значению? Попробуйте:

    form.menu.field.choices.0.1

где 0 - первый элемент выбора, 1 - второй элемент кортежа элемента выбора (т.е. его наименование)

Comment: Да, нужно отобразить именно то пользователь выбрал через меню. После выбора пользователем варианта создаётся XML файл в который передаётся выбранный вариант именно в этом виде. Если в выпадающем меню выбрано 'Choice 1', значит и в XML должно появится именно 'Choice 1'. На месте 'Choice 1' может быть строка любого вида, в том числе c русскими буквами и символами -'АБВГД?:*";№)*%;'. Если вбить идентичные значения то у сформированного выпадающего HTML меню будет вид, например - <option value="АБВГД?:*";№)*%;">АБВГД?:*";№)*%;</option>, что не очень корректно.
Ваш код пишет - ошибка синтаксиса

Comment: Исправил ответ - посмотрите, а то здесь в комментарии столько писать нельзя :)

Comment: вот ещё:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display

Comment: спасибо! я просто не использую модели, поэтому этот вариант мне не подойдёт. но всё равно ваши подсказки навели меня на другие интересные мысли. правильный же ответ ниже. именно то что я хотел

Answer (score 0):

Понаписали в ответах какие-то манкипатчи

Люди, читайте документацию! Есть же DjangoBook в конце концов.

```
GENDER_CHOICES = (
    ('M', 'Male'),
    ('F', 'Female'),
)
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENDER_CHOICES)

>>> p = Person(name='John', gender='M')
>>> p.save()
>>> p.gender
'M'
>>> p.get_gender_display()
'Male'
```

[Источник](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display)

Да и гугл всегда в помощь.

Comment: Еще и наминусовали. ППЦ.
Автор вы пробовали, вариант с get_FIELD_display()? Неужели не работает?

Comment: У автора не используются модели. Советую внимательнее читать вопрос.